# loop in R is returning different ggplots than the manual code

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a loop that's nested inside a larger function (but I've pulled it out since it's the only part malfunctioning). When I run the code through the loop, it loops correctly through the vertical line dataframe, but only plots the third column of the histogram dataframe (code below). However, if I run the exact same code manually, everything works correctly.

Loop code:

```
plts1 <- list() 
for (i in 1:ncol(rep_coefs)) {
  plts1[[i]] <-  ggplot(rep_coefs, aes(x = rep_coefs[[i]])) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 10) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = og_coef[[i]], color = "red") +
    labs(x = names(rep_coefs)[i])
}
grid.arrange(grobs = plts1, nrow = 1, ncol = ncol(rep_coefs))
```

Output:
[plots from loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mVgh.png)

Only the third column in rep_coefs gets plotted in the histogram, but it cycles through the og_coef data correctly as a vertical line and the names correctly as the label for the x-axis.

The exact same code, manually looping through the columns.

Manual code:

```
plts2 <- list()
plts2[[1]] <- ggplot(rep_coefs, aes(x = rep_coefs[[1]])) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 10) +
  geom_vline(xinterceplts2 = og_coef[[1]], color = "red") +
  labs(x = names(rep_coefs)[1]) 

plts2[[2]]<-ggplot(rep_coefs, aes(x = rep_coefs[[2]])) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 10) +
  geom_vline(xinterceplts2 = og_coef[[2]], color = "red") +
  labs(x = names(rep_coefs)[2]) 

plts2[[3]]<-ggplot(rep_coefs, aes(x = rep_coefs[[3]])) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 10) +
  geom_vline(xinterceplts2 = og_coef[[3]], color = "red") +
  labs(x = names(rep_coefs)[3]) 


grid.arrange(grobs = plts2, nrow = 1, ncol = ncol(rep_coefs))
```

Output: [plots made manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXy3P.png)

The replication data can be found here: [link to data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1uqna2tb01gri58/AAAaG6628qucDCASOeeGbopWa?dl=0)

Comment: The `aes()` values are saved as unevaluated expressions. That means that `i` isn't evaluated until the plot is drawn, not when it's built. You can inject the current value with some tidyeval syntax: Try `aes(x = rep_coefs[[!!i]])` or `aes(x=.data[[names(rep_coefs)[i]]])`

Comment: thanks so much! that was exactly it